# Sorting abstract datatypes in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, types, sql-order-by

For example I have the following,

```
type something = (Float, Float, Int, Aa, Bb, Cc, Int)
```

If I were to desire to find the smallest `something` in base to their first element *(Float)* how could I do that? The way I have reasoned it is the following, yet I cant manage to figureout how to implement it

Because I have a list of `somethings` the easiest way should be to create my own `min` helper function that compares `2 somethings` and returns the smallest of the two. However it is trying to do that "easier way" that got me stuck with *type* compile errors...

```
findMin :: something -> something -> somthing
findMin x y = sortBy (compare `on` fst) x y
```

I am not familiar with `sortBy` and `compare on`, I just came across a similar question here in SO but I couldnt manage to make it work. As a beginner in Haskell, is there another way to approaching this?.

Comment: "fst" and "snd" only work on tuples with two elements.  For anything longer you are probably better off with "data Something = ..." as others have suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a custom `data` type is usually the better option, but if you really want to use tuples, you can start by defining a helper function `comparingFst` that compares based on the first element of the tuple.

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

-- Dummy data types for example purposes. Derive from Show just so
-- that the example can be more easily tested interactively in ghci.
data Aa = Aa deriving Show
data Cc = Cc deriving Show

type Something = (Float, Float, Int, Aa, Cc, Int)

comparingFst :: Something -> Something -> Ordering
comparingFst = comparing fstSomething
    where fstSomething (x,_,_,_,_,_) = x
```

Now you can take the smaller of two elements with:

```
findMin :: Something -> Something -> Something
findMin x y = case comparingFst x y of
    LT -> x
    _  -> y
```

or from a list of elements

```
findMinimum :: [Something] -> Something
findMinimum = minimumBy comparingFst
```

And you can also use the same helper function for sorting:

```
sortSomethings :: [Something] -> [Something]
sortSomethings = sortBy comparingFst
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that tuples are, by default, compared element-wise, starting from the first element, so assuming your `Aa` and `Bb` types can be derived from `Ord` and `Eq`, you don't need anything extra, i.e. the example becomes:

```
import Data.List

data Ab = Ab deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
data Cc = Cc deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

type Something = (Float, Float, Int, Ab, Cc, Int)

findMin :: Something -> Something -> Something
findMin x y = min x y

findMinimum :: [Something] -> Something
findMinimum = minimum

sortSomethings :: [Something] -> [Something]
sortSomethings = sort
```

In other words, you can just use the standard `min` and `sort` functions as-is.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to compare based on the first field of a data type, you can let Haskell write the code for you:

```
data Something = Something Float Float Int String Bool Char Int
               deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

The `deriving` clause specifies which type classes implementations are automatically generated for the `Something` type. Here, we derive `Eq` which allows us to ask whether two `Something`s are equal (e.g., with `==`), and `Ord`, which allows us to compare two `Something`s and know which one is "greater".

Haskell's default behavior when deriving `Ord` is to compare each field from first to last, so the default code will start by comparing the first `Float` of each `Something`, which is exactly what you want.

Once you're dealing with a type that implements `Ord`, you can use all sorts of built-in functions like `minimum :: Ord a => [a] -> a`. This takes a list of any type that implements `Ord`, and gives back the smallest element. So, as an example:

```
st1 = Something 3.14 2.72 7 "hello" False 'λ' 42
st2 = Something 3.15 2.72 7 "hello" False 'λ' 42

smallest = minimum [st1,st2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You have some syntax errors, firstly.

There are two things you can do. Firstly, following the model of using an accessor function to get at the field you want (`fst`), we can define labels for the fields of your type:

```
data Something = Something { field_x, field_y :: Float,
                             field_z    :: Int }
```

and then sort on `field_x`

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

sortSomethings :: [Something] -> [Something]
sortSomethings = sortBy (compare `on` field_x)
```

getting at the mimimum is the same as taking the head off the sorted list:

```
minSomethings  :: [Something] -> Something
minSomethings  = head . sortSomethings
```

alternatively, you can write a custom `Ord` instance for the `Something` type that compares values only using `field_x`, then regular `sort` and `minimum` (and other `Ord`-based functions), will "just work".

Comment: Also, the `comparing` is `compare on`